# How do I use tail command repeatedly for a text file with multiple lines?

Tags: linux, scripting

I've been reading a lot about the tail command recently and I can't say I found the solution to my problem. I have a text file named log.txt and it contains 3 lines:

> vm2014-09 Classic Forwarded: Mla-site
>   12828034:3021:1298320 0000001110000000000     11/25/2013 2:24
>
> vm2014-10 Application Forwarded: Spc-site
>   238567034:3021:1298320    0000001110000000000     11/25/2013 3:54
>
> vm2014-11 Classic Forwarded: Mla-site
>   12828034:3021:1298320 0000001110000000000     11/25/2013 4:49

I want to get the last part of the lines
Now I have this code

```
tail -c 17 log.txt
```

and it obviously returns **11/25/2013 4:49** which is the last line of the file. I want to know how to make it return this:

11/25/2013 2:24

11/25/2013 3:54

11/25/2013 4:49

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if your `log.txt` file has a fixed structure. If so I wouldn't use `tail` but this instead:

```
cat log.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}'
```

The `sed` removes the blank lines, the `awk` returns the last two space-delimited fields. I get

```
11/25/2013 2:24
11/25/2013 3:54
11/25/2013 4:49
```

Comment: useless use of cat spotted

Comment: @perreal not constructive. tail does not solve the problem. If the file were more than 10 lines then tail returns the last 10 by default. tail -f could work if log.txt is like a logfile (maybe). The stated sed / awk addresses the question, the cat just products a text stream.

Comment: The file has a fixed structure.Thanks! It works. I did not use the cat though. I used the sed and awk. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You also have `cut`:

```
tail log.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 7,8
```

Fields 7 and 8 are the date and time, respectively. As @JayInNyc also suggests, this will only  work on the given sample lines. Lines with different formats will give unexpected results.